# Show a msgbox with missing dates where user has not enterred info

Tags: excel, vba

Im pretty new to vba and would like some advice

I have a timesheet spreadsheet where a user enters the amount of time it takes for them to complete tasks on a daily basis. Column A indicates the user and column B the date, then column c to x are the different tasks.  The data is inputted on a form on another sheet and then a macro adds the data to my sheet and shows a messagebox confirming their hours have been enterred and the date for - I would like this message box to also show any dates (earlier than todays date) where the selected user (named within a cell on the sheet) has not enterred any hours within the current year?

Sub Macro12()
'
' Macro12 Macro
' Macro recorded 01/11/2013 by christopher.hodges
'

'

```
If Range("C13") = "" Then
    MsgBox ("Please Select Department")
    Exit Sub
End If
If Range("C14") = "" Then
    MsgBox ("Please Select Employee")
    Exit Sub
End If
    If Range("C15") = "" Then
    MsgBox ("Please Enter Date")
    Exit Sub
End If
If Sheets("Form").Range("J39").Value < 7.5 Then
MSG1 = MsgBox("Hours are less than 7.5, do you wish to add?", vbYesNo, "Hours Less than 7.5")
If MSG1 = vbNo Then
Exit Sub
End If
End If
Range("E13:E35").Copy
Range("C16").PasteSpecial
Range("G13:G38").Copy
Range("C39").PasteSpecial
Range("I13:I31").Copy
Range("C65").PasteSpecial
Sheets("Data").Select
Call ShowAllRecords
Sheets("Form").Range("C13:C84").Copy
Sheets("Data").Range("A2").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=True
Sheets("Data").Rows("3:3").Copy
Sheets("Data").Rows("3:3").Select
Selection.End(xlDown).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats, Operation:=xlNone, _
    SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 1).Select
Sheets("Form").Select
Range("B16").Copy Range("C16:C83")
Range("C13:C15,E13:E35,G13:G38,I13:I32").ClearContents
Range("C15") = "=today()"
Range("A1").Select
MsgBox ("Hours for " & Range("C15").Value & " Added")
```

End Sub

Comment: Post your current code.

Comment: my current code doesnt bear any relevance to the dates missing (and is probably a complete mess but hey im a beginner :P):

Comment: oh and just to complicate things - users may have started within the year, so I only want to identify any dates between their earliest record and today

Comment: and only weekdays... think i might just leave this bit off!! lol

Answer (score 0):

I have only tested this on a small data set. Know that if you data set is very large this might not be the best way to go (although if it is very large a DB would be better anyway). but you can call like so.

```
Sub missedWork(employee_name AS String)
    Dim missedDates As String
    missedDates = missingDates(employee_name,earliestDate(employee_name))
    If missedDates <> "" Then
        msgbox "You did not enter hours for the following days: " & missedDates
    End If
End Sub

Function earliestDate(emp As String) As Date
    Dim e_date AS Date
    Dim lcell As Range
    e_date = Date()
    For Each lcell in Range("$A$2","$A$" & Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row)
       If lcell.Value = emp Then
           If Cells(lcell.Row,"B") < e_date And Year(Cells(lcell.Row,"B")) = Year(Date) then
               e_date = Cells(lcell.Row,"B")
           End If
       End If
    Next lcell
    earliestDate = e_date
End Function

Function missingDates(emp AS String, e_date As Date) AS String
    Dim lcell As Range
    Dim msg As String
    Dim c_date As Date
    msg = ""
    c_date = e_date
    While c_date < Date()
       If WeekDayName(WeekDay(c_date)) <> "Saturday" AND WeekDayName(WeekDay(c_date)) <> "Sunday" Then
          If Not(workedDate(emp,c_date)) Then
             msg = msg & vbNewLine & Format(c_date,"mm/dd/yyyy")
          End If
       End If
       c_date = DateAdd("d",1,c_date)
    Wend
    missingDates = msg
End Function

Function workedDate(emp AS String, c_date As Date) AS Boolean
    Dim lcell As Range
    For Each lcell in Range("$A$2","$A$" & Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row)
       If lcell.Value = emp Then
          if Cells(lcell.Row,"B") = c_date Then
             workedDate = True
             Exit For
          End If
       End If
    Next lcell
End Function
```